# Zipping files with perl, last line is cut off

Tags: perl, compression, zip

I tried to zip some CSV files which are about 5 MB with Perl. Below is my zip code.
The files are zipped but when I open them with the Windows unzip utility I found that the last lines of the CSV files are missing. What could be the problem here? I tried to change the `chuncksize` and the `desiredCompressionLevel` but this didn't help.

```
sub zip_util{  
   my $directory = shift;
   $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
   $zip->setChunkSize(65536);
   # Add a file from disk

   my $file1=File::Spec->catfile($directory, 'file.csv');
   my $file2=File::Spec->catfile($directory, 'file2.csv');
   my $file3=File::Spec->catfile($directory, 'fil3.csv');
   $zip->addFile($file1,'file1.csv')->desiredCompressionLevel( 6 );
   $zip->addFile($file2,'file2.csv')->desiredCompressionLevel( 6 );
   $zip->addFile($fil3,'file3.csv')->desiredCompressionLevel( 6 );

   # Save the Zip file
   my $zipped_file=File::Spec->catfile($directory,'files.zip');
   unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed($zipped_file) == AZ_OK ) {
      print  LOG ": Zip Creation error\n";
   }
```

Comment: It might be a problem with [`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive::Zip). However, to make sure, can you please upload the original CSV files as well as the archive that was generated?

Answer (score 1):

I've checked it with warnings and strictures and I've found certain problems.

1. `$zip` doesn't use `my` (I don't know if it's intentional, but `use strict` really helps with globals like this).
2. You're running `$zip->addFile($fil3,'file3.csv')`. `$fil3` variable definitely doesn't exist. If anything, this variable is `$file3`.
3. I guess it's issue during Copy and Paste, but subroutine doesn't have matching brace.

I've done quick script which I've used during testing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );
use File::Spec;

sub zip_util {
    my ($directory) = @_;
    my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
    $zip->setChunkSize(65536);

    # Add a file from disk
    my $file1 = File::Spec->catfile( $directory, 'file.csv' );
    my $file2 = File::Spec->catfile( $directory, 'file2.csv' );
    my $file3 = File::Spec->catfile( $directory, 'file3.csv' );
    $zip->addFile( $file1, 'file1.csv' )->desiredCompressionLevel(6);
    $zip->addFile( $file2, 'file2.csv' )->desiredCompressionLevel(6);
    $zip->addFile( $file3, 'file3.csv' )->desiredCompressionLevel(6);

    # Save the Zip file
    my $zipped_file = File::Spec->catfile( $directory, 'files.zip' );
    if ( $zip->writeToFileNamed($zipped_file) != AZ_OK ) {
        print STDERR "Zip Creation error\n";
    }
}

zip_util '.';
```

The problem is that it was working. So, I've done this script to make some sort of 5MB files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

for ( 1 .. 524_288 ) {
    my $number = $_ % 10;
    say "$number-------";
}
```

Both files in ZIP and original "CSV" had this same size and content. So, it's probably the second issue which I've mentioned - use of `$fil3` variable or something with your files (which you sadly didn't uploaded, so I cannot look into those).